# find a digit in $_ and add data to $_ in perl

Tags: perl, file-io

I am trying to read data from a file using File I/O in perl. I want to find an integer, compare it and add a integer to the line. My file consists of line like this.

> file mfile.txt start_value 0 end_value 13000 errors 30

I want to compare the end_value and want to add 500 or 2000 after that end_value.

> file mfile.txt start_value 0 end_value 13000 2000 errors 30

This edit has to be done in the same file. My code goes like this.

```
print "Enter file ";
$file= <STDIN>;
chomp ($file);

open ( DATA, "+<$file") || die "No file";

while(<DATA>) {
   print "$_\n";    
   @line = split / /, $_; 
   print "$line[5]";
   $epat = $line[5];
   if ($epat > 10000) {
       $line[6] = "2000 errors";
   }
   else {
       $line[6] = "500 errors";
   }
   $_ = join (" ", @line);
   print "$_";
   print "\n";
}

close DATA
```

I tried to convert $_ to array and find the end_value by calling its index and compare it. It worked fine but how to write this new edit to the same line in the same file? After this the file is not changed. How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `perl -i` to change the file in place, but you then need to populate @ARGV with the filename. It writes to another file and renames it back behind the scenes, anyway.

In fact, you can use just a one-liner:

```
perl -i~ -ape 's/(?=errors)/$F[5] > 10000 ? "2000 " : "500 "/e' -- filename
```

- `-i~` creates a backup of the file using the suffix `~`
- `-a` splits each line into the `@F` array
- `-p` reads the input or argument files line by line and prints each line after processing
- `s///e` does substitution, but interprets the replacement as code to run
- `(?=errors)` is a look-ahead assertion, it matches where "errors" start, but doesn't replace the matching part
- `? :` is the ternary operator, it corresponds to an `if then else` on the expression level

Comment: oops sorry i have a "-" before errors like -errors.

Comment: so how to take that "-" sign?

Comment: Do you mean you want to remove the sign?

Comment: No I dont want to remove that sign we have to consider the sign also. The text in the file is like this " file mfile.txt start_value 0 end_value 13000 -errors 30 " . I tried perl -i~ -ape 's/(?="-errors")/$F[5] > 10000 ? "2000 " : "500 "/e' . But it did not work

Comment: Why did you add the double quotes?

Comment: I tried double quotes becaue there was a "-" before. When tried without double quotes, the output was like "file mfile.txt start_value 0 end_value 13000 -2000 errors 30". I want that as "file mfile.txt start_value 0 end_value 13000 2000 -errors 30"

Comment: `s/(?=-errors)/$F[5] > 10000 ? "2000 " : "500 "/e` works for me.

Comment: yes it worked, sorry there was syntax error when I did that. Now its fine.